# Is this a correct usage of "來日方長"?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, usage

I want to say:

> You still have a long way to go, wish you have a memorable secondary school career

And here's my translation to Chinese:

> 來日方長, 希望你有個難忘的中學生涯

I'm wondering if it is correct to use 來日方長 here?

Answer (score 2):

It's based on your intention. `来日方长` usually used for the two situations, if you want to tell sb that

1. There's still time to do sth
2. Need not to hurry in doing sth now

现代汉语词典（第五版）：`未来的日还很长，表示事有可为，或劝人不必急于做某事。`

Comment: I actually want to tell sb he still have a long way to go, [你還有很長的路要走]
 (i.e. not these 2), then is this a correct use...?

Comment: @User2012384 If there's not an explicit object of `doing sth`, it's a little weird, even though the whole sentence could be understood without confused. If you want to bless sb, you can use `前程远大` etc.

Answer (score 1):

"来日方长" is similar to "take your time""no hurry". And we do not use "来日方长" a lot in spoken Chinese.

Comment: oh really...?! I though very often we use "來日方長"0.0...

Comment: instead of "来日方长", we use expressions like  "慢慢来"“别着急” more often.